# Unity3d Character tilts with camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

I´m currently trying to make a 3d character controller in unity. I followed and used a script from a Youtube tutorial for 3d movement and wanted some changes. In the default script the character rotates in the movement direction (when walking to the camera ("backwards") he looks in it). i wanted more like a BotW Version, where i can walk backwards, sideways, strafe etc. So I changed one line and it works like intended, exept the fact that my character tilts forward when i move the camera up and down (they share the same rotation value on the x axis).

```
 void TestRotationBehaviour()
    {
        // Ketra Games tutorial //
        Vector3 movementDirection = new Vector3(inputMagnitude.x, 0, inputMagnitude.z);

        movementDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis(cameraTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.forward) * movementDirection; 
        movementDirection.Normalize();

        Vector3 velocity = movementDirection * speed;
        velocity.y = ySpeed;
        characterController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        //custom part
        if (movementDirection != Vector3.zero) 
        { 
            Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(cameraTransform.forward, Vector3.up);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed* Time.deltaTime);
            //ToDo
            //player tilts with camera rotation on x axis. The higher the camera the steeper the tilt on the player
            
            
        }
```

float rotationSpeed = 180;

float speed = 0; i am using rootmotion in my animations

I tried to lock the x-rotation on the player but everytime i manage to set it to zero, the rotation on the y-axis stops working to and my character "ignores" the camera input when walking forward. I even tried to use an empty gameobject whose transform and y-rotation equal the camera but this didn´t work either.

The camera i´m using is a cinemachine free look cam.

I hope someone can help me,

thanks in advance

Comment: you need to make sure hes not looking at objects feet.. most objects position is their feet, not their eyes, so if you rotate to look at a position, its going to look down, which makes you tilt.

Comment: took me a while to understand (i think so) what you mean. I changed the cameras target to an empty positioned at the head of the player, but that just made it a little bit worse. i think the problem is the tilt of the camera. it matches the tilt on the player exactly. i cant find a way to get rid of that tilt without losing the player rotation feature which is what i want.

Comment: by adding this line:
toRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(cameraTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up);
after line 16 i fixed my problem. Thx

Answer (score 0):

By adding this line of code after Line 16 I fixed my problem:

```
toRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(cameraTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up);

void RotationBehaviour()
{
  // Ketra Games tutorial //
  Vector3 movementDirection = new Vector3(inputMagnitude.x, 0, inputMagnitude.z);

  movementDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis(cameraTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up) * movementDirection; 
  movementDirection.Normalize();

  Vector3 velocity = movementDirection * speed;
  velocity.y = ySpeed;
  characterController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

  //custom part
  if (movementDirection != Vector3.zero) 
  { 
    Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(cameraTransform.forward, Vector3.up);
    toRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(cameraTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up);
            
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed* Time.deltaTime); 
  }
}
```